# Issue with the plural package inside "golang.org/x/text"

Tags: go, internationalization

I am doing some tests with the [`golang.org/x/text`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text) package and particularly with the [`feature/plural`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/feature/plural) sub package and its [`MatchDigits`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/feature/plural#Rules.MatchDigits) method. Here is what I am doing :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/feature/plural"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(plural.Cardinal.MatchDigits(language.French, []byte{1}, 1, 0)) // "1" -> should print 2 (One) but prints 0 (Other)
    fmt.Println(plural.Cardinal.MatchDigits(language.French, []byte{2}, 1, 0)) // "2" -> prints 0 (Other) the correct value
    fmt.Println(plural.Cardinal.MatchDigits(language.French, []byte{1, 0}, 2, 0)) // "10" -> prints 0 (Other) the correct value
}
```

And here is where I get the expected results from : http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#fr

I also tried with another language with more complex plural rules like Czech and the output was not correct.

Am I missing something ? I can not find a lot of examples on this package.

Thanks !

EDIT:

After some more tests, I found the good result for "1", using 0 as both the `exp` and `scale` parameters :

```
fmt.Println(plural.Cardinal.MatchDigits(language.French, []byte{1}, 0, 0)) // prints 2 (One), the correct value
```

But it does not follow what the [documentation says](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/feature/plural#Rules.MatchDigits), and does not work when I try for 1,5 with the same logic :

```
fmt.Println(plural.Cardinal.MatchDigits(language.French, []byte{1, 5}, 0, 1)) // prints 0 (Other), should print 2 (One)
```

Comment: These examples works fine. Is this the problem with `Big-Little endian` byte order